# How does one disable the Midori status bar?

Tags: midori

I somehow seem to have enabled the Midori statusbar while fiddling around with the various extensions and now I can't figure out how to turn it off.

Searching the web I found a 'show_statusbar' boolean settings value for Midori, but I'm not sure where or how to toggle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on a tool item in Midori's headerbar you should see a menu that will let you toggle off the Bookmarkbar and Statusbar:

[image: Headerbar Context Menu]